# $_SESSION is giving error in codeigniter's controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Facebook login authentication in codeigniter. I have placed the facebook sdk folder in the root of website and using that in the view like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("fblogin/config.php");
include_once("fblogin/includes/functions.php");


if(!$fbuser){
    $fbuser = null;
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri'=>$homeurl,'scope'=>$fbPermissions));

}
else{
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');
    $user = new Users();
    $user_data = $user->checkUser('facebook',$user_profile['id'],$user_profile['first_name'],$user_profile['last_name'],$user_profile['email'],$user_profile['gender'],$user_profile['locale'],$user_profile['picture']['data']['url']);

    $_SESSION['email'] = $user_profile['email'];
    header('Location:/music/profile');

    } 

?>
```

If you see the code carefully, I have added the user email in a session variable. Now I want to access this session variable in my controller. I try two way for this first is this:

My controller constructor

```
 function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library("session");
        $this->load->model("Profile_model");
    }

public function index()
    {
        session_start();
        $name['name'] = $this->session->userdata("name");
        $name['email'] = $this->session->userdata($_SESSION['email']);
        $this->load->view('Profile_view', $name);

    }
```

This gives me error that a session had already been started:

> ignoring session_start(); and Undefined index: email

Second way I used is this:

```
public function index()
    {
        session_start();
        $name['name'] = $this->session->userdata("name");
        $name['email'] = $_SESSION['email'];
        $this->load->view('Profile_view', $name);

    }
```

This also give me same error as above.

Comment: did you load session helper ?

Comment: yes I load session.. Please check my question I edit that @DilipPatel

Comment: Have you checked if email index exist '$user_profile['email'];'?

Comment: Yes I am getting email from $user_profile['email']; @PraveenReddy

Comment: I do not see any $this->session->set_userdata() any where http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data

Comment: if you load session library then no need to session_start();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call the user data like this

```
$name['email'] = $this->session->userdata('email');
```

as you have already stored it. And in facebook.php you have started a session so why you want to again start a session.

Comment: now I am not able to access email on view  <?php $name['email'] ?> and  <?php $email?> I try both of this

Comment: you have to echo that then only you can view it.

Comment: ops that was my mistake but still The email is not showing to me on my view :(

Comment: can you do a var_dump($name); exit; and paste the result.

Comment: array(2) { ["name"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL } its show null.. but why? :(

Comment: have you jncluded this in your controller $this->load->library('session');

Comment: thank you so much for help me regarding this. I have added $this->load->library('session'); in profile controller but did not add this in login controller. Such a silly mistake I was doing from last 3-4 hours. anyways I just learn something and appreciate your effort for helping me :)

Answer (score 1):

Your view loads after trying to get the name and email from session. Try to load view first where you are setting the session variable, then get the values from session

Answer (score 0):

Looks like email is not receiving in $user_profile, Try testing with Facebook account who is included in app developers list.

Comment: I am getting complete data from facebook.. $user_profile['email']; contain data